# Why I am not able to add an object to an array? [javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, firefox-addon

I am trying to create a firefox addon to manage tabs in groups.

**Creating an array of objects**

I understood that arrays have the square bracket notation, and that objects have the curly bracket notation.
Objects are more likely a python dictionary than a java object, because are just a bunch of key-value sets (am I right?).

This is the code i wrote:

```
var groups = [];
var groupcounter = groups.length;

function addTab(tabs) {
    for (var tab of tabs) {
        console.log(tab.url);
        console.log(tab.title);
        groups.push({title: tab.title, url: tab.url});
    }
    groupcounter = groups.length;
    console.log("groups length = "+groups.lenght);
}

function onError(error) {
    console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}


function addToGroup(){
    browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}).then(addTab,onError);
}

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.textContent === "Add To Group"){
        addToGroup();
    }
});
```

I was expecting that for each call of addToGroup, if the Promise then "called" the success function, i get an object element inserted into the groups array.

The print on the console works fine and i am able to see on firefox debugging tool console the right output.

```
        console.log(tab.url);   // --> prints tab url
        console.log(tab.title); // --> prints tab title
```

But when it comes to add the object to the array, I always got undefined (I tried many ways).

```
    console.log("groups length = "+groups.lenght); //--> prints 'groups length = undefined'
```

---

**Questions and Thoughts**

- May it be a scope problem? I know that declaring the variable outside of the function makes it global.
- I was wondering if it was possible to pass directly the object to the push
- Javascript objects don't have constructors?

Comment: You have a typo - `lenght` should be `length`..

Comment: `console.log("groups length = "+groups.lenght);` please correct spelling length in your code and then try again

Comment: Pro tip: Don't begin your question with a paragraph of text explaining how you describe yourself as lazy and don't have the time to learn things.  Just focus on the question itself and the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Oh god... i can't believe i am that stupid... why javascript interpreter didn't tell me there is a mis-typed word?

Comment: @David thank you for the tip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is a typo `groups.lenght` should be `groups.length`

Answer (score 1):

you have wrongly typed `lenght`. It must be `length` at line:

```
console.log("groups length = "+groups.lenght);
```